# Unit Testing framework for Embedded platform in C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, ace

I am working on an embedded systems project using ACE Framework and all the development is done using eclipse IDE. I am looking for a good testing framework.
Basically the project involves parsing of incoming data and I am searching for a unit testing framework which suits my project. What are my options here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you try out [Catch](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) or [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest), which are quite similar.

Comment: My team has Cath2 working on a STM32 discovery (Cortex M-4), so this is a possible choice indeed.

Comment: Testing doctest for STM32 (m4)

Comment: @Bktero I checked the feature list for Catch, and it doesn't mention mock support or embedded support. How does it work with STM32 in your experience -- compiling for Linux and running there, or compiling to run on the STM32 device?

Comment: @CivFan that was a long time ago, I'm sure if I remember all this! Indeed, Catch2 doesn't have support for mock objects. It doesn't need anything special for "embedded support". From what I recall, you can do something like this: ```#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
Catch::Session session;
session.configData().testsOrTags.emplace_back("[some tag]");
session.run();
```
The test results will be printed to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Try ceedling: It is UT framework from throw the switch,
from http://www.throwtheswitch.org/ceedling

Comment: More general thing.

Comment: According to its website, ceedling doesn't support C++

Comment: @volpato, yes, it supports C.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this light-weight unit testing framework designed for embedded software use with C++ that I created:
https://github.com/Novodes/SimpleTest-EmbeddedSafety/

It was tested with ARM Compiler version 6.6.4 and 6.6.
There are just two files: simpletest.cpp and simpletest.h

This is based on the [SimpleTest](https://github.com/kudaba/simpletest) repository I forked and adapted for embedded software. It is super easy to use and integrate into your code.